# Generate Random Unique Code

Tags: c#, .net, algorithm, random

I need to generate a nine digit numeric code (random preferably) which is unique for a given day (same number cannot be generated again on the same day). I was thinking of using HHMMSSmmm (hours, minutes, seconds and milliseconds) to generate the unique code but is not really random. This code generation method can be accessed by multiple methods at the same time so I will have to put a lock on the method. But will this ensure that the number is unique as it is possible that number generation may take less than a millisecond and two threads get the same number?

Is there a better way to generate a random unique numeric code which is unique for a given day? The number of digits can be from 6 to 9 digits.

**Edit:** The number of random numbers to be generated depends on the number of transactions. Initially the number could be lower but over a period of time it can become very high (multiple transactions per second). Hence, I would not like to compare the number against a used list as this could have performance issues.

Randomness is needed as this number will be entered by the user on the phone. This number is the only way to link the online transaction with the phone transaction so I don't want user to enter a different number by mistake.

The random number generation needs to take place in a ASP.NET MVC application.

Comment: @achinth do they have to be **numbers**?

Comment: I think you already answered your question. The issue there is it's predictability.

Comment: A regular System.Guid won't do?

Comment: They need to be numbers only !!

Comment: @tzup that's why I asked it. Do you have a way to convert a `Guid` object to a number trying to keep them as unique as they were in the Guid?

Comment: It cannot be greater than 9 digits and have to be a number as one may need to enter this number on a phone.

Comment: You omit a crucial bit of information: **how many of these unique nine-digit random numbers are you creating per day?** Because if you're creating two or three per day, that's a lot easier problem to solve than if you're creating twenty million. If you're creating a trillion per day then the problem is not solvable; there aren't that many nine digit numbers available. (Coincidentally, I often ask your question as an interview problem; it is astounding the number of candidates who never think to ask how many numbers they're dealing with.)

Comment: Also, on the subject of time: don't forget also that on the day when daylight savings time "falls back", there are *two whole hours* in that day when two physical times can have the same clock time. Clock time is not unique, so don't try to use it as a source of uniqueness.

Comment: Can you also describe why "randomness" is important? There are many different reasons for something to be "random" and each puts a different requirement on the randomness generator. Cryptographic randomness is very different from pseudo-randomness, for example. Do you actually require non-predictability for a security reason?

Comment: @Eric: Is your interview questions available on the net? I was wondering if you have a fixed list of questions you use all the time or make them up as you go in the interview, depending on the person?

Comment: @Joan: I don't use this question so often anymore, so I might blog it at some point. I have a small list of problems I like to use, depending on the level of the position.

Comment: @Eric: Thanks Eric. Seems like great questions to really test one's thought process.

Comment: @achinth as you can see from the comments/answers, there are many elements involved to solve the problem. You really want to post an update to the question to include answers to @Eric comments, and if this is within the same process as @Jon mentioned.

Comment: I have updated the question to answer all the queries

Comment: What is wrong with pre-generating the numbers? (as suggested in my answer)  I fail to understand why this is a problem.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you start from a random number with 6 digits, then keep adding random, but small enough numbers, you may be abled to do that. You can use the filesystem as the locking storage if you want... but I think you should use a DB for production!

**Here is the sample of what I am talking about:**

This sample is a console application, that uses a file to control concurrency, and to store the last used number and date it was generated.

If you run it multiple times you will see what happens. Both will have their own unique numbers.

It ***will NOT store all generated numbers***, like you required!

This sample can generate for about 999000 random numbers per day, in the range of 6 and 9 digits inclusive. That is about 11 numbers per second.

```
using System;
using System.IO;
namespace _5893408
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Random rand = new Random();
            var futureTime = DateTime.Now.AddSeconds(60);
            while (DateTime.Now < futureTime)
                Console.WriteLine(GetNextNumber(rand));
        }

        public static int GetNextNumber(Random rand)
        {
            var now = DateTime.Now;
            string filePath = @"C:\num.txt";
            FileStream fileStream = null;
            while (fileStream == null)
            {
                try { fileStream = File.Open(filePath, FileMode.OpenOrCreate, FileAccess.ReadWrite, FileShare.None); }
                catch { }
            }
            using (fileStream)
            {
                DateTime date;
                int prevNum;
                if (fileStream.Length == 0)
                {
                    date = now;
                    prevNum = rand.Next(100000, 999999);
                }
                else
                {
                    var reader = new StreamReader(fileStream);
                    {
                        date = DateTime.Parse(reader.ReadLine());
                        prevNum = int.Parse(reader.ReadLine());
                    }
                    if (date.DayOfYear != now.DayOfYear)
                        prevNum = rand.Next(100000, 999999);
                }
                int nextNum = prevNum + rand.Next(10, 1000);
                fileStream.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);
                using (var writer = new StreamWriter(fileStream))
                {
                    writer.WriteLine(now);
                    writer.WriteLine(nextNum);
                }
                return nextNum;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I think that this fulfills your requirements... am I wrong?

If I am, just tell and I'll try to help more.

Comment: In case of a secure callback mapping, wouldn't this make it a bit predictable.

Comment: @YetAnotherUser: Yes... a bit! But it may be possible to make it less predictable using some sort of integer math... like the maths used in cryptography, doing large prime sums and then module.

Answer (score 1):

**EDIT:** This answer doesn't make sense when I realised the requirement to have multiple unique codes per day, but that they can repeat the next day. If you were looking for a single unique code per day (for whatever reason), then this answer is useful :)

so if the code is just required to be unique per day, then just use the date as the code...

maybe YYYYmmdd, which would give you (for today's date) 20110505, and tomorrow would be 20110506.

Comment: @AlastairPitts That's what he said, but I don't really think he wants one code per da. Otherwise he wouldn't be thinking about two methods accessing in the same second :/

Comment: @AlastairPitts yes, that's what he said ;)

Comment: The code should not repeat in a give day, it can repeat the next day

Comment: @achinth: Ahh ok. I see what you mean now. I misread what your requirement was :)

Answer (score 1):

Does it only have to be unique within the process?

Any reason not to just keep a counter which you increment atomically each time, and then reset it if the date rolls over?

Comment: Good idea, but I would like some randomness in the numbers. Is it possible Jon?

Comment: @achinth: There are various ways you could include randomness - the simplest to implement would be to remember all the values you've created so far today, generate a random number and check whether or not you've returned it. That wouldn't scale well *at all* (horribly, in fact) but it would work if you don't need to generate many numbers. Note that using the time is far from random...

Comment: @achinth I think you should add all the necessary info to your question. If you are looking for a way to generate unique numbers, here you have one. Now, if you want random numbers... you should have added it into the question. Maybe you could tell us what the scenario is...

Comment: @jon the number generation needs to be quick so I don't want to check against existing numbers if possible.

Comment: Another issue of assuming in process and keeping a list of already generated numbers, is if this is an asp.net app that would have to survive a recycle.

Comment: @eglasius: Yes, that's true. If the values are actually being stored, you could make the process read "today's values" on startup to work out the initial value to use. It wouldn't work well within a more distributed environment of course.

Comment: agreed / btw, downvote is not mine, I do find it a reasonable answer given the lack of specs in the question

Answer (score 1):

If all the calls are within the same JVM, I think all you'd need is to create a static to hold the last number assigned, write a single function to increment the number and return the new value, and then synchronize on it. Like:

```
public class NumMaker
{
  static long num=0;
  public static synchronized next()
  {
    return ++num;
  }
}
```

If there are multiple JVMs, the easiest thing to do would be to store the number on a database and use database locking to keep the numbers unique.

**Update**

I see you've added a requirement that the numbers be random. If you want the numbers to be random AND unique, I don't see any alternative to keeping a list of all previously assigned numbers. You could keep them in some sort of hash table so you don't have to search the entire list each time. If you're assigning a lot of these the size of the hash table may begin to be a problem, even if you don't have to sequentially search it.

Depending on what you're trying to accomplish, you could come up with a scheme that assigns numbers non-sequentially but in a rigid sequence, so for some purposes they would appear random. For example, you could increment by a number that is very large with respect to the maximum and relatively prime with the maximum, and then every time the next increment would go over, subtract the maximum. Like just to scale it down, suppose you were assigning 2 digit numbers instead of 9 digit. Increment by 37. Then you'd assign 37, 74, 111 wraps to 11, 48, 85, 122 wraps to 22, etc.

Comment: @Oscar: Oops, my secret Java bigotry slips out! I meant, of course, the .NET runtime.

Answer (score 1):

Use Guid.NewGuid() to get something like:

0f8fad5b-d9cb-469f-a165-70867728950e

Then, get rid of the '-'s, and convert the letters to their ASCII counterparts. (where a=97)

Then convert to a number.

Comment: I need the number to be between 6 and 9 digits and I don't want to check for uniqueness against existing numbers if possible.

Comment: This is a bad idea. GUIDs are larger than 9 decimal digits, and GUIDs are only guaranteed to be unique when you look at *all* their bits. Any given subset of bits in a GUID is not guaranteed to be unique, any more than any individual part of an airplane is the part that flies.

Comment: Only taking the first 6-9 bits of a GUID is obviously not going to guarantee uniqueness, therefore the need to check against already allocated ids. OP wants to avoid that if possible so he can choose among the other suggested answers.

Answer (score 1):

I would

1. Generate a set of unique random numbers at the beginning of each day, or rather, before each day in adequate time
2. Sequentially take a number from the stack every time one is needed

Answer (score 1):

You **CAN'T** ensure than random numbers will not repeat. (because, they're random)

Without a comparison with already generated numbers, you can have:

- random number **OR**
- unique number.

You need unique number with some random-look. If the milliseconds from the beginning of the day has not enough random look, try combine it with *another* unique number.

For example:

- combine number of milliseconds, and
- atomic counter (what is increment by one every time you generate a number)

for example when you sum them, you can generate:
999999999-86400000 = 913599999 unique numbers per one day.

While they will be not random, they will be unique - and predictable only at 00:00.

Here are variations for this, for example not resetting the counter at 00:00.

Answer (score 1):

How about a modified version of ***Shuffle Bag***. Here's how it would work -

1. before your Start of day, you put N distinct numbers satisfying your criterion in a shuffle bag
2. during the course of day, you request a number from shuffle bag.
3. Shuffle bag gives you a random number from bag and discard it - i.e. will not return the same number again.
4. at the end of the day it would clear the bag, ready for next day.

Benefits

- Ensures number is not reused, without checking with existing list
- Numbers would be random, without any sequence
- Apply simple sanity rules to initialize Shuffle Bag, for e.g. no common / repeating sequences allowed (1111111 or 123456789)
- Simple to initialize shuffle bag - use random sequential numbers. i.e. start from six digit number keep on adding a small random number to initialize bag.
- Easy to modify the size of bag based upon historical usage.
- Very simple thread safe implementation in c#.

Original source is [here](http://kaioa.com/node/53#the_shufflebag) - modified version might serve your purpose.

- [Never-ending Shuffled Sequences - When Random is too Random](http://kaioa.com/node/53)

Answer (score 0):

Append a thread id to the end of the code to deal with concurrency.

Comment: Suppose you append the thread id to the current time. Now suppose that the id is created at the beginning of the hour when daylight savings time "falls back". One hour later, the same thread is asked to produce an ID, and it produces the same ID as before, contravening the requirement that it be unique. The problem here is that times are not unique. Appending more stuff to them does not improve the situation.

Comment: Let's look at another problem with your solution. Suppose you have a two-part ID. The first part is guaranteed to be unique on a given thread, the second part is the thread ID.  You generate an ID.  Then that thread ends. A few hours pass. A new thread is created and it happens to get the same ID. That's a different thread, so it could generate the same first part as the earlier thread, and the IDs are the same, so again, we don't have uniqueness.

Comment: The long and short of it is: neither time nor thread handles are actually sources of uniqueness on every day. **You can't make uniqueness out of two things that are themselves not unique.**

Answer (score 0):

The suitable code generator depends on how much numbers should be generated in period.
Consider following patterns:

HHMMSS+NNN- gives you space for 999 random numbers in a second.

HH+NNNNNNN - gives you space for 9999999 random numbers in a hour. Etc.

If number generation method call distribution in time is uniform, then any pattern is almost equal.

Anyway, considering random number lenght restriction there is always a limit for number of method calls before clashes will apper. E.g. if method is called > 1000 times per second.

Answer (score 0):

I continued your idea to use current time, I just added multi-thread synchronization, and storing used randoms to compare all next randoms with them to provide uniqueness.

```
private static DateTime DateInArray = DateTime.Today;
private static ICollection<string> UsedTodayRandoms = new List<string>();

[MethodImpl(MethodImplOptions.Synchronized)]
public static string RandomUniqueToday()
{
    if (! DateTime.Today.Equals(DateInArray) ) {
        UsedTodayRandoms.Clear();
        DateInArray = DateTime.Today;
    }

    string result = null;
    DateTime timeToGenerateUnique = DateTime.Now;
    do
    {
        result = timeToGenerateUnique.ToString("HHmmssfff");
        timeToGenerateUnique = timeToGenerateUnique.AddMilliseconds(-1);
    } while (UsedTodayRandoms.Contains(result));
    UsedTodayRandoms.Add(result);

    return result;
}
```

Comment: I would like to avoid comparing against a used list as it could result in performance issues.

Answer (score 0):

`public double GetRandomNumber() {object operation = new object(); lock(operation) { return new Random().NextDouble(); } }` would do.

This does not depend on the day/time hence its even more random then your requirement.
Now the fact that the number is less then 1 I'll leave to you as an exercise ...

Also, if you like to keep track of all number generated for a given day - keep a list of them and regenerate if duplicate is generated. But that I will not write for you as you are the programmer in your situation ...

Comment: There are two problems with your solution. First, a new Random() class that hasn't been seeded with a number will use the current system's time for a seed value. That means two created within ~15 milliseconds(Windows system clock resolution) of each other will most likely produce the exact same values. Locking will not prevent this. Second, since the object you are locking on was created within your method, it will never actually block anything since other threads will have created their own new objects to lock.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on just how much randomness is required, a [linear congruential generator](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_congruential_generator) with the appropriate parameters may be what you are looking for.  For example, following the guidelines given on the Wikipedia entry about period length, a set of parameters that might work for you is: M=1000000000, a=21, c=3, then use any initial seed X<sub>0</sub> in [0..999999999], and compute X<sub>n+1</sub>=(a*X<sub>n</sub>+c)%M.  This generates a sequence of X<sub>n</sub> with period M, i.e., the sequence generates all numbers in [0..999999999] exactly once before starting to repeat.